# Iterator-like concept that generates data

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a (large) number of images files on the disk.  I would like to iterate through them and do something for each image.  I can not load all of them up front, I would like to load the image only when it's needed and dispose it just before I load the next one.

I implemented this with boost:iterator_facade and input iterator that loads the image in operator().  It works, but I encountered a number of difficulties which tell me that probably the iterators are intended to iterate over external sequence rather than to own the data.

I was wondering if there is some standard c++ idiom for this, sort of data owning iterator?

EDIT: the code I wrote is [here](https://gist.github.com/alexkreimer/a06f1634e7889a664d44)

The "difficulties" are with

```
image_pair& dereference() const {...}
```

1. I would like to return `image_pair`that is a part of the object, but since the dereference() is a const method, I cannot do that
2. Because of the same reason, I cannot load the images in dereference method (sice this changes the object), so I have to do it in increment()

Thanks

Comment: It might be considered a stream, of sorts, assuming you only want to iterate 'foward'. But I don't see any particular reason why wyou coudl not engineer a file-iterator class with an iterator-like interface,

Comment: Iterators behave very similar to pointers, so they don't really own the data. You can create a collection of shared pointers (`std::shared_ptr`) or unique pointers (`std::unique_ptr`)  to your objects, then manipulate the collection via iterators, so you will be able to directly change the referred objects and not copies of them. Not sure if this is what you want though...

Comment: What sort of "difficulties"?

Comment: You can totally make iterators own data, you just have to be careful.  Namely, they have to have _shared ownership_ of the data, so each iterator has to have a `std::shared_ptr` to their shared state.  It's not all that hard really.  Also, `boost::function_input_iterator` is designed for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Duck this was really close :) Unfortunately function_iterator requires no-parameters constructor, which I cannot provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator is expected to give a reference to a value, but that doesn't prevent it from managing that same value.

Consider the alternatives (1, 2):

1) So far I have found the functor interface the easiest to implement. A code using a functor might look like

```
auto images = Image::all(); while (auto image = images()) {image->doSomething();}
```

where `Image::all` returns `std::function<boost::optional<Image>()>` implemented by either a functor class or a lambda.

2) Rook's idea of using a stream looks really nice and idiomatic. Might look like

```
Images images; Image image; while (images >> image) {image.doSomething();}
```

where `operator >>` returns `Images&`, its `operator bool()` returning false when the stream is finished.

3) But I see the iterators used for that kind of thing all the time, like the [recursive_directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator). And the reason for this is the reuse of the generic algorithms, like `std::find` and `std::copy`. Imagine using `std::copy` to create a backup of your images:

```
std::copy (images.begin(), images.end(), backup.begin());
```

This is very succint, idiomatic and follows the principle of least astonishment.

I would say it's your choice, as a developer, whether to use a functor (aka [generator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Generator.html)), a stream, iterators or something else, but the iterators approach is usually the most friendly towards the users of your API.

Comment: Great answer. It’s a shame that C++ doesn’t consolidate iterators and generators more, since to me, generators are little more than a restricted interface (or maybe a facade) to one specific type of iterator (input iterator). Same for streams, incidentally. This answer shows all their strengths quite nicely.

Comment: The idea of using a stream sounds very appropriate and cool (I really should have thought about this).  Honestly,I dislike streams for their messy (IMO) APIs.  The functors are great, too, but as you note they miss the ability to apply standard algorithms (which iterators provide).  I guess I should have been more precise with the question.  I am looking for an iterator based idiom to solve this nicely.  I will take a look at recursive_directory_iterator, may be it will show me the way :)

Comment: The closest thing to idiom that I know of is to have an object with the `begin` and `end` methods. (Boost `iterator_range` might be used to create such an object from two iterators). `recursive_directory_iterator` uses another idiom where an *empty* iterator is used as the end iterator. e.g. `for (RDI it("path"), end; it != end; ++it)`.